# Can`t create a virtualenv using Python

Tags: python, django, pip, setuptools, python-wheel

I am trying to create a `virtualenv` but I just get stuck with this message:

```
python -m virtualenv env
New python executable in /Users/r13/env/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...
```

What is going on?

Comment: Whats wrong? Please mention the error?

Comment: You want my opinion? Use Docker, then you don't have to deal with virutalenv.

Comment: But you have to deal with Docker @qräbnö :D

Comment: Did you try pressing enter?

Comment: @Pitto: OK, but docker-compose was easier for me to learn than virtualenv. But the docker-compose successor docker-swarm still put me off a little bit, just as it did virtualenv in those days.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to install virtualenv:

```
pip install --upgrade virtualenv
```

Then to activate it:

```
virtualenv -p python envname
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as there is no error during setting up virtualenv, it can only be considered as a lack of resources on the local machine. Please wait until the end, when virtualenv is finished setup or an error occurs